# How correctly make a select ng-repeat into another ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have to write something like that

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="pers in persons">
     <td>
        <select id="person{{pers.id}}">
           <option ng-repeat="city in cities" value="{{city.id}}" ng-selected="isOptionSelected(pers,city)">{{city.name}}</option>
        </select>
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But I'm facing some showing problems on IE and I suppose that write something wrong. 
Have I to fix a ng-model on the select?

Thanks in advance

Comment: this is not a correct code. ng-selected with function is wrong.

Comment: Why aren't you using ng-options ?

Comment: I's exactly what I'm doing and it seems to work better.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the pers.id as an ng model for the select, and use ng-options for the select's options.

```
<select ng-model='person-{{pers.id}}'
        ng-options="city.name for city in cities">
```

You can set the default selection in the controller.

Docs for ng-repeat [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Comment: Can you elaborate on why it is better to use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`instead of just `ng-repeat`?

Comment: ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end let you choose if you want to repeat more than a single html tag, which is useful for repeating **<tr>** or **<td>** without repeating the table headers.

Comment: I understand, but that's only better if you actually need to repeat multiple elements.  It's not better in general, and not better for the example in the question.

Comment: You're right. The ng-repeat-xxx it's of no use on this example since the first repeat is on a single <tr>